# JQL syntax not working with slaSearch

Tags: jira, jql

I am trying to create a filter that takes in all incidents that are in progress, and have less than or equal to 25% left of their SLA-timer.

issuetype = Incident AND status = "In Progress" AND vertygo in slaSearch(remaining, "<",26%)

The base for that syntax I got from https://jira.valiantys.com/browse/VSLA-917 from Diego Calas in the third comment.

We do have Jira version 6.3.3 which can use the percentages.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://confluence.valiantys.com/display/VSLA/Searching+SLA+Data)

VertygoSLA uses a single JQL function to run all search options:

```
<custom_field_name> IN slaSearch(x, y, z)
```

For instance, you can use

```
GTR in slaSearch("remaining", "<", "90%")
```

So use the following

```
issuetype = Incident AND status = "In Progress" AND vertygo in slaSearch("remaining", "<","26%")
```

Comment: I get an "Error occurred communicating with the server. Please reload the page and try again." message, though I copypasted your answer.

Comment: issuetype = Incident AND status = "In Progress"  and "Timer on Resolution" IN slaSearch (remaining, "<", "26%") Using that doesn't return an error message, but none of the incidents fit the query.

Comment: Did you go through the documentation link?